# TestNG TestListener - How to reach testmethod parameter in TestListener beforeInvocation method

Tags: testng

The parameters in xml file are set inside the `<include>` tag, something like this:

```
<suite name="Suite">
  <listeners>
    <listener class-name="..MyTestListener"/>
  </listeners>
  <classes>
    <class name="Foo">
      <methods>
        <include name="myTest">
          <parameter name="parameter1"  value="parameterValue"/>
        </include>
..
```

Of course I can reach the test parameter in beforeInvocation method if the parameter tag is outside of the include tag, example: `method.getTestMethod().getXmlTest().getParameter("parameter1")`. But in this case parameter is necessary to be bound to the test method, and I get null as getParameter method return value.

Thanks, Stristi

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer for my question. IInvokedMethodListener beforeInvocation method has ITestResult parameter, which has getParameters and setParameters methods. Or IHookable interface allows you to handle the input parameters of the testMethod, and call back the testMethod.

Br, Stristi

Answer (score 0):

As per the dtd [here](http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd.php), parameters can be defined at the `<suite>` or at the `<test>` level.
Parameters defined at the  level override parameters of the same name in `<suite>`.  So, one cannot associate a parameter at class level.

Also, a `<test>` in testng means a set of classes eg [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml).  You can probably refer to the [part of testng documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#introduction), where testng xml nomenclature is explained, if it helps. The parameters in the `<test>` tag, can be referred by all the classes that fall under it.

Comment: It is possible to define parameters for
individual tests in testNG since 2011 December.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, if you are talking about a test> tag in a testng xml, then it means a set of classes or a single class.., so for a test tag in a testng xml you can specify a parameter  and these can be accessed using @Parameter in individual testcases i.e ATtests in your code.  But you cannot have a <parameter> tag inside <methods><include>.  You need to keep it outisde the <classes> tag, either in the <test> tag or the <suite> tag.

Comment: Visit this forum: http://groups.google.com/group/testng-users/browse_thread/thread/867380549828f01a/4b0776faeba2df1b?lnk=gst&q=Parameters+for+test+cases+in+the+XML+#4b0776faeba2df1b

Comment: Guess I missed that feature..thanks for letting me know and apologies for my being so adamant on keeping the parameter tag outside the methods tag :)  Will give the feature a shot!