# Testng : Get invoked method parameter information in a listener

Tags: testng

I need to get information about method invocation in a method listener at runtime. Precisely the value of the parameter passed to the method thru a data provider.

Here is my Test Class

```
@Listeners(MyListener.class)
class MyTest{

   @Test(dataProvider="myDataProvider")
   public void myTest(ITestContext context , SomeParam param){
      // test something
   }    
}
```

Here is my listener

```
public class MyListener implements IInvokedMethodListener2{
  // other methods omitted

 @Override
 public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, 
           ITestResult testResult,  ITestContext context) {

    // so i have access to the invoked method thru the "method"
    // argument.
    // I need to print the value of SomeParam that was 
    // passed to the method  
    // what do i do here to get access to the 
    // instance of SomeParam that was passed to the method ?

    SomeParam param = method.what().to().call();
    System.out.println(param);

}
```

Comment: In eclipse debugger when I watch the IInvokedMethod argument I can see the parameters being passed in the against m_parameters

So the "method" instance being passed does contain it somewhere.. Question is how do i access it.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538996/testng-testlistener-how-to-reach-testmethod-parameter-in-testlistener-beforein?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parameters are stored in testResult not in method so `testResult.getParameters()` works fine.